# RDLC Group not insert Page Break if Table bigger than 1 Page (Data Print/Export)

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, rdlc

My problem is only in Tables longer than 1 page, and only when i export/print data (Primarly in PDF format).
I've a report that is structured like below grouped by "Team" (I use "GroupProperties" --> "PageBreak" --> "Between Each Instance Of a Group" to insert the page break):

```
TeamName:   MyTeam 

service1      6         50.00

service2      10        30.00

service3      5         20.00

service4      21        90.00

------PAGE BREAK-------

TeamName:   MyTeam2 

service5      7         250.00

service6      6         500.00

service7      62        750.00

service8      50        1000.00

------PAGE BREAK-------

TeamName:   MyTeam3 

service9       7         250.00

service10      6         500.00
```

It works great since the number of the team rows fit 1 page, but if one of the teams has more rows than the number of the rows that the page can handle, the 2nd page miss the page break between the Teams (that it should be inserted by the option "PageBreak - Between Each Instance Of a Group"). Example:

```
TeamName:   MyTeam 

service1      6         50.00

service2      10        30.00

service3      5         20.00

service4      21        90.00

------PAGE BREAK-------

TeamName:   MyTeam2 

service5      7         250.00

service6      6         500.00

service7      62        750.00

service8      50        1000.00

------PAGE BREAK------- (Because i reach the end of the page with the rows of "Team2")

service98     62        750.00

service99     50        1000.00

// NO PAGE BREAK HERE IS TRIGGERED!!!!!

TeamName:   MyTeam3 

service9       7         250.00

service10      6         500.00
```

Is a Report limit or i'm missing something?
Thanks,

*EDIT*:

- Using the Flag "Also at the end of a Group" i see nothing changed.
- Using the flag "Also at the start of a Group" i go the error:

  > ScalableList: Index -1 outside the allowed range [0::1]

Comment: Try Page break at start.

Comment: I try both, at start and at the end, but nothing worked :( Using PageBreak At Start i got the following error:
ScalableList: Index -1 outside the allowed range [0::1]

Comment: A probably [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55709155/9709907).